# Strange Image Comes Out on Taskbar Every Several Minutes

Tags: windows-7

I suddently got this program on my taskbar, running every several seconds and closing immidiately so I can't check what exactly it is (or its executable name). Here's the icon on taskbar I got via recording my screen on a screen recording tool and then get the screenshot:

[image]

A [google image search](https://www.google.com/search?tbs=sbi:AMhZZisMfrU3-k1fgrDrt0OSY05ogZaAi0R3iRpQx0afJn1PdXacVWvIHAgLH8yq6wz-_1ZPIST-DY7UHMd72oE_19jagkr5cyLS7nsyhoWfRccJ2iyNtaW15WfgQc2AO5DiA97RQbzfYfIDrMvlXMqdWrAJDgS-YnFBz227k50ScowG5a0c0tdkJTf4zXm08v4wXZAE_1PeTblgMxRNaeZ5yoD6MciavPkH_16x5HnJKBd1zH2AJKtyId-FYT8yP4Z1YQcwZjmhZLL5ZNXJVojKZowkoXJGTflIZo0KyrfxDwg-WWAKCcDkSC26W6w1HLHP9zNgFKG0GM2LlQCAHrIhtTmxA2WLcCexwRtsFOzbilxJJ108bkoGeMoGdTjgypLiNMjB9sn0i6tS4Cl4kh9LbfpdWfmgaB6C06nKZ-gDssOLRhGhFwn8ZEGZ4T3R-Yu3lOCLsowPdNvdrqSzGDmaNsCP33Bf6nbVBpkWdUjrQuma3eUTR8USNUtK6xhlSsYxtJ28JveQuvE1doX08ucmBrpAWAqdhJE1s4YZZDDVTDFqclse1R4KCHGbJcfudi9B02NX00-sc2_192UWv2aGEdBcKkhIChkUNV-LyIkeEf_1d3F7mE3rPjEvr7wCYtyhkrNhPVoxSLqsI6fw4LcJ-Ep_1OKeDko-Jf7HLw2Zks7EGCEE3xNwsP5_1zNorG6lohghRHxuVM-Dap_1WW1TpOY2YXW4zSZYNHDGw900BdKmDo_1_1eqN_18dxBUDtOMD62_1vV5N0yeyJ5SPSYxhy_1x5PrSk33zzW8qEIHDaFwQWsmDdMfgSrE6uvmLZS9-ED9LfCmLw3UVoR8Ye6S1zSLM1_1n-mVlGzCAgQIBBAk6aBKpy7VcGRprq3uivX9pGZHsv3qwpxkiHsxuOylzCGyRail22UQVmzPjgH81laFtN-JqLi25EC5jI50K2NhkWahY2tS20gjJtEAHMk02pzMYi4ZprO0OOOGox3EX4vqZnOhU-kA2mTOl1H8cL1rwHJIxiI1TlekMM-au6xHQZz_1A5cXkTziqoCh3SVkbxoIfgCmiYXGrdTdiO0L2MSsbL1GTeqrbAsVcVUV02UqZMNElGqgkKSgSnyE0F2rLuJia5I-m4lUgeeOuiRt1umdaWS9hD4Xw0Wg3pQXC11Vza7cF4ANZ2Vr2IM6rHJ-7lLE-JrI-RaYcB6FHi8ZqttTB_1MtQzsajHtlpXaGLKvyPJR6wNMuquuBR5eI319OtuHOEcSVRWx0N5zWO8yqVde510_1d3I-Jx78WKXVnKb3NrKAw0DkvEDkmGuD8keuUPD1rA&num=10&hl=en&safe=off&bih=775&biw=1600) show some Chinese forum and [this forum](http://www.sevenforums.com/general-discussion/214432-help-strange-icon-taskbar.html) which said that it is an executable called liveupd.exe, but I've search around and can't find such executable. I'm afraid my computer might have been infected with some sort of keylogger or screen capturing tool. Have someone ever have the same problem? Anyone knows what this is?

Thank you very much.

Comment: `liveupd.exe` is often associated to the "AOpen Display Drive LiveUpdate Wizard", which pops up intermittently to check for updates.  Have you got any Acer/AOpen devices attached (or perhaps it's an AOpen computer)?  Does anything by AOpen appear in your add/remove programs?

Comment: @techie007 it's a HP laptop, and I don't use any device from Acer/AOpen. I've search on add/remove program and there's no AOpen... Is his some sort of generic program icon?

Comment: to make matter worse, I don't remember installing things recently, but I also rarely restart my computer (like maybe once a month). I just restarted today and found that program. Checking msconfig and startup folder yields no result too...

Comment: Have you got any external devices plugged in?  If so, and you unplug it/them, does it keep doing it?  Have you checked `MSConfig` for possible related start-up entries?

Comment: @techie007 `MSConfig` is clear. I've been using a new keyboard pas month, a Razer one. Currently trying to unplug it.

Comment: @techie007 just confirmed, still showing up after I unplugged the keyboard...

Comment: Autoruns will show you more stuff than msconfig.
http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/bb963902.aspx -

Comment: @Jonathan sorry for the late reply, there's already a great answer below. Thank you very much :D

Answer (score 3, accepted):

OK I saw this icon on a Windows 7 computer today.  It's the icon for the "Interactive Services Detection", which is part of Windows since Vista.

[image]

It's caused by Services and/or Processes running under the System or another account in the background, which are requesting Desktop Access.

Since Vista and above separate this from the user session, this Icon would (if you could click on it fast enough) lead to a pop-up, that would allow you to see the message(s) the background process is trying to display, and find out what's displaying it.

[image]

More info here: [What is Interactive Services Detection and Why is it Blinking at Me?](https://web.archive.org/web/20160303050545/http://blogs.msdn.com:80/b/patricka/archive/2010/04/27/what-is-interactive-services-detection-and-why-is-it-blinking-at-me.aspx)

This page: [Troubleshooting Interactive Services Detection](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/archive/blogs/patricka/troubleshooting-interactive-services-detection) explains some troubleshooting tips on how to deal with it.

It has a specific section entitled "*The Tile Button is Displayed Too Quickly and I Can't Click it Fast Enough*", which sounds like what you're running into.

It has instruction on how to use the Windows Event Viewer to capture the Interactive Services Detection process and log it, that way you can check out the Event Logs to see what's triggering it.

Here's the instructions they provide:

- From the Start menu search box, type `eventvwr` to start the Event Viewer.
- In the tree view in the left pane, right click *Custom Views* and select *Create Custom View*...
- In the *Custom View* dialog, select the "By Source" radio button and then select *Interactive Services Detection* in the "Event sources" drop down box.

[image]

- Click OK.
- In the "Save Filter" dialog, name your custom view. e.g. "Interactive Services Detection".
- Click OK. You are now configured to capture these events when the occur.

Then, the next time you see the Interactive Services Detection icon appears on the taskbar, you can return to the Event Viewer and investigate the information that has been logged.

Example ("Calculator" was what tried to pop up the message):

[image]